# ADFS SAML Response with Different Destination and Recipient URLs

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

Is it possible to configure a Relying Party in ADFS to send the SAML Response to a Destination URL while having the Recipient URL in the SubjectConfirmationData block be a different URL?  I haven't seen anyway to configure those two to be different in the ADFS UI.  Our use case is that we have a proxy we want to send the SAML Response through en-route to the service provider (us in this case) which is expecting the Recipient URL to be a certain value.  We obviously can't manipulate that value in the SAML Response using the proxy itself since those responses are signed from the IDP.

Comment: I checked and there is no available way to configure the relying party in ADFS in the above way you have mentioned. URL must match the one that you specify in the Service provider ID field of the web server IdP configuration document.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that - that's the conclusion I came to as well after a couple days of trying to find a way to make that happen with ADFS.  Good to get confirmation from someone else as well.

Comment: @PurrBiscuit Did you get that as an official answer from Microsoft? having the same issue

Comment: @makat just the response from the MSFT Identity user below so far.  I haven't figured out a way to get this to work through ADFS yet.  It's been awhile since I've looked into it any further as well.

Comment: @Thirgiftthub-MSFTIdentity any chance you could reply here?

Answer (score 0):

I checked and there is no available way to configure the relying party in ADFS in the above way you have mentioned. URL must match the one that you specify in the Service provider ID field of the web server IDP configuration document.